# What exactly is represented by the template parameter passed to std::function template?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, std-function

`std::function` itself offers a great utility- it provides type erasure in order to generically store / provide access to callables. Its flexibility is great:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void printer() {
    std::cout << "I print!";
}

int adder(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    std::function<void()> fun1 = printer;       // fun1() calls printer()
    std::function<int(int, int)> fun2 = adder;  // fun2(1, 2) calls adder(1, 2)

    std::function<void()> fun3 = [](){};        // fun3() will do nothing - same for the lambda
    std::function<int(int, int)> fun4 =
            [](int a, int b) { return a + b; }; // fun4(1, 2) will yield the sum
}
```

And, to be honest, everything makes sense. `std::function<void()>` says that it's a `function`, which, when called, returns `void` and takes no (`()`) arguments. Ditto for `std::function<int(int, int)>` - when called, it returns an `int` and requires two `int`s as its arguments.

While intuitive, I believe I lack fundamental understanding of that exactly **is** the explicit template parameter. What exactly is `void()` or `int(int, int)`? They cannot be function pointers, becasue when I do:

```
int main() {
    using type = void();

    type x = printer;
}
```

I get the following warning and an error:

> ```
> main.cpp:15:10: warning: declaration of 'void x()' has 'extern' and is initialized
>  type x = printer;
>       ^
> main.cpp:15:14: error: function 'void x()' is initialized like a variable
>  type x = printer;
>           ^~~~~~~
> ```

Well, obviously it looks like a variable - I *wanted* it to be a variable. However, if I wanted a function pointer, I would've had to do:

```
using type = void(*)();
```

instead of:

```
using type = void();
```

What exactly is the type with omitted `*`? What exactly is represented by the intuitive explicit template parameters when used with, for example, the `std::function`?

Comment: Well, it's... a function.

Comment: `int(int)` is a type. `int foo(int)` is a possible function of that type. `int(*)(int)` is a pointer to that types. Functions have their own type, like objects.

Comment: @Quentin well, that's both very specific and very unspecific. If it's a function, can I declare it? Can I later define it? Can I declare and define it? What are the rules around that? What's the relevant part of the standard which describes the bahaviour around it? I'm happy to take a read :>

Comment: Note that `type * x = &printer;` *is* valid.

Comment: @Caleth very useful comment - it does shine some light on the type system, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What exactly is the type with omitted *?

Think about it. A type "followed by" a `*` means "pointer to that type". If you don't "follow" a type with a `*`, then the type means just that type. So if you have a function pointer, then it is a pointer to... a function type.

Therefore, types like `void()` are function types.

Function types are distinct from object types, but they are still types. So you can play most of the type-based games with them that C++ allows. But since they're not object types, you cannot create objects of function type.

Comment: So... it's just like that? That's just a special syntax for providing a type of a function, used **only** when providing a type to match a passed function?

Comment: This should probably mention that the function type is just a syntactic nicety for `std::function`. [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) should really be `template<typename R, typename... Args> struct real_function;` It's not *really* a `template<typename F> struct function`; `std::function` just tears function types apart to get to `R` and `Args` so you can use the more suggestive syntax.

Comment: @HTNW That makes it sound like this kind of type was put into the language for the sake of `std::function`.

Comment: @HTNW: That's an implementation detail and is irrelevant to the question of "what is that type?".,

Comment: @Fureeish I mean, it's not *that* special. If you'll notice, function declarations are actually using function types: `void func(int);` is declaring `func` with type `void(int)`.

Comment: @Fureeish It's not really a special syntax, maybe just used less frequently. There all sorts of *kinds of* types that are incompatible and use different notation, including member pointers and member function pointers. None are more or less special, though perhaps less often used.

Comment: @NicolBolas The question's wording implies (to me) that OP thinks that `std::function<F>` actually stores a value of type `F` or `F*` or something somehow. It doesn't. `std::function`s hold arbitrary callables, and the type of its `operator()` is what is taken from its template parameter.

Comment: @HTNW I agree that the question doesn't seem to concern itself with how `std::function` works and I believe it just uses `std::function` as an example of a use case for function types to better illustrate what is being asked. The question appears to me to be about what a function type is. Anyway, how `std::function` stores it's callable thing doesn't really impact how it's conceptually thought about. As Nicol Bolas puts it, it is an implementation detail.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux when investigating `std::function`'s implementation, I noticed the specialisation of: `template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes> class function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>`. I was wondering whether parenthesis and commas were the only allowed operators in template `<...>` context. And it does sound like the ability to specialise on that was added (was it present from the very beginning?) to help working with `std::function`. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you are correct with your assumption about my question.

Comment: @Fureeish It's true that parameter packs (ellipses in templates) was added to the language at the same time as `std::function` and `std::function` relies on them to work. But they aren't in the language just for that. You've been able to specialize with them since they were introduced and it's an incredibly powerful tool that serves many other purposes. While I am not on the standardization committee and can't speak to it's intents, motivations and history, I would be very surprised if that feature was implemented *specifically* to support `std::function`. It's too generally useful.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I didn't have parameter packs in mind. I was talking about parentheses. The "`<...>`" part of my comment was very misleading, I admit. `_ArgTypes...` is no mystery, the fact that you can do `_Res(_ArgTypes...)` (focusing on the `()` part) is.

Comment: @Fureeish I see. In that context `_Res(_ArgTypes...)` is just specializing for when a type template argument is a function type with the return type `_Res` and the arguments defined by the parameter pack `_ArgTypes...`. You can use any kind of type in template type arguments including non-object types like references, functions and member pointers. The history of template features is unclear to me, but as far as I know, this was supported at least as far back as c++98. At least, I can't find that change in any "new features" lists for modern version of the language.

Comment: @Fureeish To be more precise, parenthesis aren't acting to "group" terms like they would in a mathematical expression. They are used here in the same way as when a function is being declared or called, to delimit the function parameters list.

Answer (score 3):

> What exactly is `void()` or `int(int, int)`?

They are function types. Eg. if you declare `void foo()`, type of `foo` is `void()`:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
  static_assert(std::is_function_v<int(int, int)> &&
                std::is_function_v<void()> &&
                std::is_same_v<decltype(main), int()>);
}
```

[LIVE](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nTVQzU)